# Python Beginner - How to splice a list of objects with the frequency of an object's attribute

Tags: python

Given:

```
from collections import Counter

class TEST:
    age = 'unknown'
    city = 'unknown'
    def __init__(self, a, c):
        self.age = a
        self.city = c
    def __repr__(self):
        return "(" + str(self.age) + "," + self.city + ")"

L = [TEST(20, 'LA'), TEST(30, 'NY'), TEST(30, 'LA')]
```

I would like to count the frequency of the 'City' attribute:

Desired Output:

`[[20, 'LA', 2], [30, 'NY', 1], [30, 'LA', 2]]`

Comment: Note that the lines setting `age` and `city` initially both to `'unknown'` are unneeded and don't do what you probably expect - they set `TEST.age` and `TEST.city` rather than being associated with any instance.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track if you're thinking about using `Counter` - it can't do the splicing you want, but it *will* get the frequencies for you. Since you want the frequencies based on just the city, tell `Counter` about just the cities:

```
freq = Counter(l.city for l in L)
```

Then `freq['LA']` will be the frequency associated with `'LA'`. You want a list of tuples `(age, city, frequency)` - the objects in `L` will give you the age and city directly, and you now have an object that gives you the frequency when you give it the city. This means you can get your desired result from a simple list comprehension:

```
[(l.age, l.city, freq[l.city]) for l in L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
res=[x.city for x in L]
op=[]
for x in L:
   op+=[[x.age,x.city,res.count(x.city)]]

print op

**[[20, 'LA', 2], [30, 'NY', 1], [30, 'LA', 2]]**
```

Comment: It is usually worth replacing code of the form: create an empty list, for ...: append exactly one item to that empty list with a list comprehension since it is almost always easier to read and can possibly be a bit faster. Also, instead of calling the linear-time `list.count` on a static list in a loop (for quadratic time overall), using a `collections.Counter` will perform a linear time operation (iterating over the entire list) *once*, and then looking up its results in the loop is amortized constant time for linear complexity overall.